# What libraries is my ASP.NET Core 7 Web API really using and how do I get a SBOM of it?

Tags: .net, dependencies

I use DTrack to get informed if my application has security issues. Therefore I have to create SBOMs of my application and here starts my problem.

For example: I create a blank .NET 7 application (`dotnet new webapi -o TodoApi`).

Then I add `MongoDB.Driver.Core` as a NuGet package and get some implicit dependencies as well.

One is `System.Memory - V4.5.5`.

My tooling (syft or sbom-tool) will create a SBOM with the corresponding entry:

```
<component bom-ref="pkg:nuget/System.Memory@4.5.5?package-id=0f5664b7f3521e96" type="library">
      <name>System.Memory</name>
      <version>4.5.5</version>
      <cpe>cpe:2.3:a:System.Memory:System.Memory:4.5.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*</cpe>
      <purl>pkg:nuget/System.Memory@4.5.5</purl>
      <properties>
        <property name="syft:package:foundBy">dotnet-deps-cataloger</property>
        <property name="syft:package:language">dotnet</property>
        <property name="syft:package:metadataType">DotnetDepsMetadata</property>
        <property name="syft:package:type">dotnet</property>
        <property name="syft:location:0:layerID">sha256:650b301b26d84cbba0f7c215211bc5ec3c4bb429d93362505698d99a8c2f9d1e</property>
        <property name="syft:location:0:path">/app/ToDoApi.deps.json</property>
      </properties>
    </component>
```

My problem is that this library is not part of my build or published application. What my application will use seems to be the `System.Memory.dll` of the .NET 7 framework. At least this dll is copied to the output folder if I publish a stand alone application.
But DTrack would warn me about security issues for a dll that my application is not using.

In the created SBOM none of the framework dlls are listed but I am quite sure they are a part of my Web API.

There has been an new cataloger (dotnet-portable-executable-cataloger) for syft that is actually creating   an output with all the framework dlls as well.

With this configuration I get the following output:

```
<component bom-ref="pkg:nuget/System.Memory@7.0.1023.36312?package-id=58ade9d797b85bfa" type="library">
      <name>System.Memory</name>
      <version>7.0.1023.36312</version>
      <cpe>cpe:2.3:a:System.Memory:System.Memory:7.0.1023.36312:*:*:*:*:*:*:*</cpe>
      <purl>pkg:nuget/System.Memory@7.0.1023.36312</purl>
      <properties>
        <property name="syft:package:foundBy">dotnet-portable-executable-cataloger</property>
        <property name="syft:package:metadataType">DotnetPortableExecutableMetadata</property>
        <property name="syft:package:type">dotnet</property>
        <property name="syft:location:0:layerID">sha256:c7a4596c3ec7605d9c1a841ff4f0ab3b599cca6d7bc04347e2e6037448cd0ec2</property>
        <property name="syft:location:0:path">/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/7.0.10/System.Memory.dll</property>
      </properties>
    </component>
```

The version of the package is now equal to the file version of this dll but I am wondering if there will be a CVE addressing this version that is actually not existing in the NuGet package manager.

DTrack in the end is telling me to update the version from 7.0.10 to the latest 4.5.5.

Why are the tools adding libraries in the wrong version to the SBOM?
Why is my application working nonetheless? (The difference between 4.5.5 to 7.0.10 should be quite great).

And why are there NuGet packages with the same name as the .NET framework libraries but totally different versions?

In the end I want to achieve that DTrack will inform me about security issues about the libraries that my application is using including the framework dlls as well as excluding not used dependencies.

But I am also really interested in the answers to the above questions.